# Удалить из масива все значения checkbox

Tags: массивы, checkbox, php, форма

Есть два массива, которые формулируются посредством парсинга ТХТ файла

```
 $bedurltv=file_get_contents('engine/modules/tvprogram/txt/bedurltv.txt');
 preg_match_all( '/<url>(.*?)<\/url>/is', $bedurltv, $bedurl);
 preg_match_all( '/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/is', $bedurltv, $titlek);
```

после чего из них формируется форма (таблица с записями и чекбоксами)

```
<form method="POST" action=""><table ;="" border="0;" width="100%"><tbody><tr>
    <td width="30%"><b><big>Название</big></b></td> <td width="60%"><b><big>Адрес</big></b></td> <td width="10%"><input onclick="CheckAll(this,'type[]')" type="checkbox">Выделить все </td></tr><tr>

    <td width="30%"><b>УТ-1</b></td> <td width="60%">/onlain-tv/10190.html</td> <td width="10%"><input name="type[]" value="<url>/onlain-tv/10190.html</url><title>УТ-1</title>" type="checkbox"> </td>
    </tr><tr>

    <td width="30%"><b>УТ-1</b></td> <td width="60%">/onlain-tv/10190.html</td> <td width="10%"><input name="type[]" value="<url>/onlain-tv/10190.html</url><title>УТ-1</title>" type="checkbox"> </td>
    </tr><tr>

    <td width="30%"></td> <td width="60%"></td> <td width="10%"><input name="delete" value="Удалить" type="submit">
    </td>
    </tr></tbody></table><br><br>
</form>
```

Как мне из этих массивов удалить выделенные значения, и сформировать два новых массива уже без удаленной информации?

Количество чекбоксов может меняться каждый раз...

собственно как получить список выделенных чекбоксов? а именно их значения value="" после этого уже можно пройтись в цикле и сравнить два массива (исходный и полученный из ПОСТ запроса) и сформировать
конченный массив

**Добавлено**
суть проблемы в чем, у меня есть файл, в нем есть текст:

```
<url>/onlain-tv/10190.html</url><title>УТ-1</title><url>/onlain-tv/10190.html</url><title>УТ-1</title><url>/onlain-tv/10142.html</url><title>УТ-42</title><url>/onlain-tv/10157.html</url><title>УТ-57</title><url>/onlain-tv/10190.html</url><title>УТ-1</title>
```

некое подобие XML мне нужно вывести форму редактирования этого файла а именно таблицу в каждой строке которой выводится ЮРЛ, название и поле для установки галочек (тоесть например как список новостей в ДЛЕ, или список писем...) пользователь отмечает из этого списка нужные ему строки и нажимает на кнопку удалить.... в результате должен остаться файл без тег строк которые выбрал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробегаетесь циклом по массиву и используйте `preg_replace`:

```
preg_replace('#(<input.*?type=["\']?checkbox["\'].*?>)#is', '', $text);
```

Comment: вы не так меня поняли, есть форма со списком чекбоксов, список сформирован из двух массивов, при нажатии на кнопку нужно из тех массивов удалить выделенные элементы, и сформировать два новых массива уже без удаленной информации для дальнейшей работы с ними...

Comment: @arashvg вам нужно удалить по выражению: '/<url>(.*?)<\/url>/is'?

Comment: собственно как получить список выделенных чекбоксов? а именно их значения value="" после этого уже можно пройтись в цикле и сравнить два массива (исходный и полученный из ПОСТ запроса) и сформировать
конченный массив

Comment: @lampa, нет, суть проблемы в чем, у меня есть файл, в нем есть текст:

Comment: <url>/onlain-tv/10190.html</url><title>УТ-1</title><url>/onlain-tv/10190.html</url><title>УТ-1</title><url>/onlain-tv/10142.html</url><title>УТ-42</title><url>/onlain-tv/10157.html</url><title>УТ-57</title><url>/onlain-tv/10190.html</url><title>УТ-1</title>

Comment: некое подобие XML мне нужно вывести форму редактирования этого файла а именно таблицу в каждой строке которой выводится ЮРЛ, название и поле для установки галочек (тоесть например как список новостей в ДЛЕ, или список писем...) пользователь  отмечает из этого списка нужные ему строки и нажимает на кнопку удалить.... 
в результате должен остаться файл без тег строк которые выбрал